# LoginRequest error in SendPostReqAsyncTask

Tags: java, android, request

This is my code:

The problem is on the `SendPostReqAsynkTask` class, saying that this class must either be declared `abstract` or `implement`abstract method  `doInBackground(Params) in 'AsyncTask`. 
What should I do? 
I have some problems with the login request I'm working on and if you could give me some advice, some easier methods to implement, sources, etc. it would be very helpful.

```
public void sendPostRequest(String url, String method, final String jsonex) {
            class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>
            {

                protected void onPreExecute()
                {
                    try {
                        showProgressDialog("Please wait...", "Logging in...");
                        //Log.d(TAG, "show");
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You are implementing a background task you need to implement the doInBackground() method to accomplish async task. Else implement volley library

Comment: Well here I may have a problem too.. I'm quite new into android and I still learn some things, basic I could say. Can you give me an example of this method?

Comment: Start reading about Async Task you will find a lot of examples as well as there methods too.

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example